# Array chunking - Possible in one Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, chunking

Lets say i have this

```
    var array =[23,345,6,765,54423,45654,7657,43,43,5,765,3456,768,897,545,645,87,4556,432,543,534];
var chunkEachBy = [3,2,1,5,6,4];

var chunked = [];


for(var i =0, l = chunkEachBy.length; i < l; i++)
{
     chunked.push(array.splice(0, chunkEachBy[i]));   
}
```

output:

```
[Array[3], Array[2], Array[1], Array[5], Array[6], Array[4]]
```

which simply chunks `array` into the length of the `chunkEachBy`, then chunk each value for each `chunkEachBy`.

My question is, instead of pushing the result of this into a seperate array in this case named `chunked` can this all be done to the original array and produce the same result?

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/b7twnurm/1/

Comment: `array = chunked` at the end of the code? You can't logically write an array in a loop if you need to access it in read mode to create the new one.

Comment: Ah well, i was hoping that i wouldn't need to declare a whole new var - so there is no way to chunk the original array?

Comment: Could you provide an example of result?

Comment: @BenConnorHansell yes you could definitely do it (in a loop, contrary to what Jack wrote), but it's not clear why you're interested in doing that.

Comment: an example, of which result? trying to chunk the original array - which simply becomes empty = [].

Comment: @Pointy: so you'd write the original array while you're reading it in a for cycle to create the new data? What'd you use as index, if you're shrinking it?

Comment: @Pointy the reason i whsh todo because in my real code i'm declaring double the amount of arrays(RAW and chunked) which looks messy. So i was wondering instead of having a separate array just to push the chunked process into like above, just chunk that original array.

Comment: Well you're going to end up building the "chunks" as new arrays anyway, no matter where you put them.

Comment: @Jack See the answer below from Siguza.

Comment: @Pointy actually I was considering a loop involving the array to splice as index, Siguza's solution involves a loop with chunkEachBy as cycle index, which indeed does not change :)

Comment: @Jack right - it just has to make sure that it plucks the values from the source array *before* overwriting the original entry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a double `splice` with `i` as index:

```
array.splice(i, 0, array.splice(i, chunkEachBy[i]));
```

Explanation:

`i` points to the first element of the `array` that we have not yet processed, or after the last element we added.
The `splice` taking two arguments (`array.splice(i, chunkEachBy[i])`) removes a number of elements from `array` from position `i`, and the one taking three arguments inserts them all back to the position they were just taken from, but now as an array (because that's what `array.splice` returns).

Also see the [array.splice documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for the third parameter.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b7twnurm/2/

Comment: Also, i didn't realize that splice could take a third parameter!

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! Now, i'm going to test the speed of doing this against declaring and pushing the result into an array - i'll write back to see which is better!

However i will still use this, as it's much tidier than what i have!

Answer (score 1):

Try the follow:

```
var array = 23,345,6,765,54423,45654,7657,43,43,5,765,3456,768,897,545,645,87,4556,432,543,534];
var chunkEachBy = [3,2,1,5,6,4];
var chunked = [];

for(var i =0, l = chunkEachBy.length; i < l; i++)
{
     array.unshift(array.splice(i, chunkEachBy[i]));   
}
```

Comment: This works too, however it does miss off the final value of the last chunked array, so a +1 would be needed - chunkEachBy[i]+1